# Error moving file to HDFS with Popen in a Python script when running as a cron job

Tags: python, hadoop, cron, subprocess

I have a Python script that moves a file from a server to HDFS using the following command:

```
from subprocess import Popen
.
.
filename = "/home/user123/test.csv"
put = Popen(["hadoop", "fs", "-put", filename, "/data/test"])
```

The script works perfectly when I run it on the server, but when I run it as a cron job it fails with the following message:

```
OSError: [Errno2] no such file or directory
.
.
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py, line 1335, in _execute_child 
    raise child_exception
```

I tried replacing "hadoop" with "/usr/bin/hadoop" but I still get a "No such file or directory" error. I assume this is an environment variables issue but is there a way to get around it?

Comment: `$PATH` may be different in `cron` environment.

Comment: Thanks, the issue seemed to be that I was setting the $PATH to Anaconda in my crontab in order to make my Python scripts work. I ended up creating a bash script for each Python script that just included the Path statement and executed the Python script, then I set my crontab to run the bash scripts and it worked. I'm still wondering if there is a better way to do this though.

Comment: Why can't you specify PATH in crontab itself?